# Template MyTemplate does not exist Odoo 15

Tags: button, odoo

Can someone help?
I wan to add a custom button in POS Odoo 15 CE.  I followed this article: https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-buttons-in-pos-using-owl, but It's seem that something has changed from verssion 14 to 15.

This is my js file in **my_project/static/src/js** directory:

```
odoo.define('numenapp_buyer_name.alias_button', function(require) {
    'use strict';

    const PosComponent = require('point_of_sale.PosComponent');
    const ProductScreen = require('point_of_sale.ProductScreen');
    const { useListener } = require('web.custom_hooks');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

    class AliasButton extends PosComponent {
        constructor() {
            super(...arguments);
            useListener('click', this.onClick);
        }
        is_available() {
            const order = this.env.pos.get_order();
            return order;
        }
        onClick() {
            const cli = this.get_client();
            alert(cli.name);
        }
    }
    AliasButton.template = 'AliasButton';

    ProductScreen.addControlButton({
        component: AliasButton,
        condition: function() {
            return this.env.pos;
        },
        position: ['before', 'OrderlineCustomerNoteButton'],
    });

    Registries.Component.add(AliasButton);

    return AliasButton;
});
```

This is my xml file in **my_project/static/src/xml** directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="AliasButton" owl="1">
        <div class='control-button'>
            Alias
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

And this is my ****manifest**.py** file (a piece):

```
'data': [
     # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/views.xml',
    'views/templates.xml',
],

'demo': [
     'demo/demo.xml',
],

'qweb': [
    'static/src/xml/AliasButton.xml',
],

'assets': {
    'point_of_sale.assets': [
        'numenapp_buyer_name/static/src/js/**/*',
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no `qweb` entry anymore.

From [bundles](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html#bundles) documentation:

> The bundles are defined in each module’s `__manifest__.py`, with a dedicated `assets` key that contains a dictionary
>  
> `web.assets_qweb`: all static XML templates used in the backend environment and in the point of sale.

Link all qweb .xml in `web.assets_qweb` bundle like following:

```
'assets': {

    'web.assets_qweb': [
        'my_project/static/src/xml/AliasButton.xml',
    ],

},
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!!! It worked right away!!!